# Importing home-baked cake into the EU

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, eu

It is forbidden to bring milk and eggs into the EU, but what about (home-baked) cake containing milk and eggs? Is the cooking considered to make it safe?

Comment: "It is forbidden to bring milk and eggs into the EU." - Not necessarily. Where are you traveling from?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: outside of Europe (I think all the exceptions are for European countries neighbouring the EU)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that you wish to 'import' from outside of the EU...

**tl;dr cakes are ok**

The controlling reference for your question is *COMMISSION REGULATION (EC) No 206/2009
of 5 March 2009 on the introduction into the Community of personal consignments of products of animal origin and amending Regulation (EC) No 136/2004* and an explanatory note is here http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=CELEX:32009R0206:EN:HTML

The regulation prohibits both milk and eggs **in some forms**. However Article 7 lists the exemptions...

> 7. Exempted animal products.  The following products are exempted from the rules explained previously:
>
>    - bread, cakes, biscuits, chocolate and confectionery (including    sweets) not mixed or filled with meat product,
>    - food supplements packaged for the final consumer,
>    - meat extracts and meat concentrates,
>    - olives stuffed with fish,
>    - pasta and noodles not mixed or filled with meat product,
>    - soup stocks and flavourings packaged for the final consumer,
>    - any other food product not containing any fresh or processed meat or    dairy and with less than 50 % of processed egg or fishery
>        products.

The UK (an EU signatory to the EU regulation) has this to say about it...

> The following products are exempted from the rules:
>
> - bread (but not sandwiches filled with meat or dairy products)
> - cakes (but not if they contain fresh cream*), biscuits
> - chocolate and confectionery (but not if the sweets are made with high    levels of unprocessed dairy ingredients)*
> - unfilled gelatine capsules
> - food supplements packaged for the final consumer containing small    amounts of an animal product (such as fish oil capsules) and those
>     including glucosamine, chondroitin or chitosan
> - meat extracts in liquid or spreadable form (but not pate or meat    concentrates eg stock cubes, gravy granules or flavouring sachets or
>     any that contain pieces of meat) olives stuffed with fish
> - pasta and noodles, if processed or cooked (but not if mixed or filled    with meat or meat products)
> - soup, stocks and flavourings packaged for the final consumer    containing meat extracts, meat concentrates, animal fats or fish
>     oils, powders or extracts (but not if pieces of meat/fish eg when
>     dissolved in water)
> - any other food product not containing any fresh or processed meat or    dairy and with less than 50% of processed egg or fishery
>     products

Source https://www.gov.uk/personal-food-plant-and-animal-product-imports

Based upon these references, you would be allowed to bring a cake *in to the EU from outside the EU* as a personal consignment.